# Why selection update not working when I pass them into another function?

Tags: d3.js, recycle, selectall

I want to use selection repeatedly.
but update method not working.
why this happen?

Does first selection can't accept more than two data binding sequentialy?

```
// 1. prepair data
var enterData = [120, 70, 300, 80, 220];
var updateData = [300, 0, 30, 70, 320];
var exitData = [300, 80, 90, 40];

// 2. select virtual element and assign it variable
var rects = d3.select("#myGraph")
    .selectAll("rect");

// 3. enter method working.
function enter (rects, data){
  console.log("enter method!");
  rects.data(data)  
  .enter()  
    .append("rect") 
    .attr("class", "bar")   
    .attr("width", function(d,i){   
    return d;   
  })
    .attr("height", 20) 
    .attr("x", 0)   
    .attr("y", function(d, i){  
    return i * 25   
  })
}

// 4. but update not working    
function update (rects, data){
  console.log("update method!");

  // 5. without below selection phrase
    // var rects = d3.select("#myGraph")
  //  .selectAll("rect");

  rects.data(data)
    .attr("width", function(d,i){   
    return d;
  })
}

function exit (rects, data){
    console.log("exit method!");
    rects.data(data).exit().remove();
}

setTimeout( function(){
  enter(rects ,enterData)
}, 1500 )

setTimeout( function(){
  update(rects, updateData)
}, 3000 )

setTimeout( function(){
  exit(rects, exitData)
}, 4500 )
```

I know how to fix it. But I don't know why.

https://jsfiddle.net/baram204/Lteby67L/6/

Answer (score 3):

The reason is
Initially when you do:

```
var rects = d3.select("#myGraph")
    .selectAll("rect");
```

There is no `rect` DOM elements in the `#myGraph` div, so the selection is empty.

In the enter function, since the selection is empty we create as many DOMs for the data and bind the data to the DOM.

Now in `update/exit` function you are passing the same **empty selection**.
So no update/exit happens.

The correct way would be to do like this:

```
function update (rects, data){
  console.log("update method!", rects);

  // 5. re-select your data
     var rects = d3.select("#myGraph")
   .selectAll("rect");

  rects.data(data)
    .attr("width", function(d,i){   
        console.log(d)
    return d;
  })
}
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/d26bqu2p/)